WSO2 app process is not starting | Getting warning message "Waiting for required OSGi services"
I tried to restart the WSO2 application process, but it is not starting. While reviewing the logs, we repeatedly encountered the following warning messages.
"WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmiN"
When googling, it indicates that we might receive the above warning messages due to DB slowness or any DB connectivity issue. However, from the DB side, everything appears to be functioning correctly. Therefore, it seems that only WSO2 is unable to reach the database.
Could anyone please help me fix the issue?
I tried rebooting the app and DB server, and even tried creating a new DB, but I am still getting the warning message 'Waiting for required OSGi services' when I start the WSO2 app process.

Hi Karthik, what is the database you are trying here? Basically the message indicates it's waiting for a some service to start and in your case it's not starting and it's in the waiting state...
To identify the issue here we can run the OSGI console mode when we starting the IS using below command and press enter once this warn message displayed.
./wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole
Then type "ss" and enter to identity what are services not started yet.
